# Implement missing members - add async when return type is Task?

Tags: resharper

This question relates to ReSharper. If I have an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface IOrder {
    Task SetDeleted(Guid id);
}
```

and my class inherits from that interface, I would expect ReSharper to generate the following code, when selecting the "**Implement missing members**":

```
public class OrderService {
    public async Task SetDeleted(Guid id) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

However, it completely ignores the `async` part of the method, so I have to type that manually every single time. This was fixed in 2016.3 of ReSharper, as described [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/01/30/code-generation-improvements-in-resharper-2016-3/) (at the bottom).

However, it does not work for the `CTRL` + `.` keybinding (or whatever it is), that looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to somehow change, how this behavior works within ReSharper? I want all generated `Task` methods to be `async` automatically. There is no option within ReSharper's "Members Generation" that enables me to do this.

Answer (score 6):

In case class has only one missing member ReSharper doesn't show dialog therefore you can't tweak generation options. But you can add one more member to your interface and invoke generation action, this time ReSharper would show the dialog where you can set option "Make task-returning methods 'async'". This generation option is persistent i.e. it's last value will be stored in ReSharper settings and used by default.

Comment: You can use CTRL+SHIFT+I to open "insert missing members" dialog even with one member.